# How to fix Python TypeError and AttributeError

Tags: python, shell

I am new to Python and I had written some code, when I run the code, I got some compile error. Could someone please help me figure out what went wrong.

This is what contain in my temp.log file:

```
06 May 19 03:40:35 3 abCodeClearTrap Error Clear Trap (agent: 12367a12, 
chassis:12367a12, ErrIdText: ERROR ID TEXT, csssi: EXTIFG, clearedID: 
0x089088394)
06 May 19 03:44:35 3 abCodeErrorTrap Error Trap (agent: 12368a15, chassis: 
12368a15, ErrIdText: Skip this item, csssi: SSRSSR, clearedID: 
0x089088394)
```

Some code I have so far: 
     #!/usr/bin/python
     import re

```
 with open('temp.log') as f:
     lines = f.readlines()

 data = []
 for line in lines:

     date = re.match(r'\d{2} \w+ \d{2}', lines).group(0)
     time = lines.split()[3]
     ids = lines.split()[4]
     agent = re.search(r'agent:\s(.*?),', lines).group(1)        
     errID = re.search(r'ErrIdText:\s(.*?),', lines).group(1)
     clear = re.search(r'clearedID:\s(.*?)\)', lines).group(1)

     row = [date, time, ids, agent, errID, clear]
     data.append(row)

 for row in data:
     print(row)
```

When I run the above code, I got:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "./practice.py", line 10, in <module>
   date = re.match(r'\d{2} \w+ \d{2}', lines).group(0)
 File "/usr/lib64/pythong2.7/re.py", line 137, in match
   return _compile(patter, flags).match(string)
 TypeError: expected string or buffer
```

Also, If I comment out line 10, the next error in ran into is:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "./practice.py", line 11, in <module>
 time = lines.split()[3]
 AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'split'
```

Could anyone please help me figure out these error.

Many thanks in advance

Comment: You launch `for line in lines:` but never use `line` incide a loop. I thinkm you need to replace `lines` to `line` in all operations incide loop.

Comment: Just use line instead of lines in your loop.

Comment: The next error I ran into is "AttributeError: 'Nonetype' object has no attribute 'group'

Comment: Ask about one error at the time. StackOverflow aims to provide (multiple) answers to a single, practical problem. It's not really meant as a discussion forum or mentoring platform.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the working version of your code. Some typo errors like line instead of lines and group() instead of group(0) but you're doing fine.

```
import re

with open('temp.log') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()

data = []
for line in lines:
    date = re.match(r'\d{2} \w+ \d{2}', line).group()    
    time = line.split()[3]
    ids = line.split()[4]

    try:
        agent = re.search(r'agent:\s(.*?),', line).group()
    except:
        agent = 'agent:'
    try:
        errID = re.search(r'ErrIdText:\s(.*?),', line).group()
    except:
        errID = 'ErrIdText:'
    try:
        clear = re.search(r'clearedID:\s(.*?)\)', line).group()
    except:
        clear = 'clearedID:'

    row = [date, time, ids, agent, errID, clear]
    data.append(row)

for row in data:
     print(row)
```

EDIT:  Add try and except when keywords are not found in the log file

Result:

```
['06 May 19', '03:40:35', '3', 'agent: 12367a12,', 'ErrIdText: ERROR ID TEXT,', 'clearedID: 0x089088394)']
['06 May 19', '03:44:35', '3', 'agent: 12368a15,', 'ErrIdText: Skip this item,', 'clearedID: 0x089088394)']
```

Comment: Hello there, I made my changes like what you have and still have the  "AttributeError: 'Nonetype' object has no attribute 'group'

Comment: Some entries in your log has missing keywords. I will update my answer.

Comment: Thank you very much, it's working now. Sorry but do you know what wrong with my "date". I still have the AttributeError: NoneType object have no atttribute group for date.

Comment: Probably the date has some format or data issue. Use try and except on date as well; then print(line) to see what is the actual data.

Answer (score 4):

As the errors both say, `lines` is a list. Presumably you meant to use `line` throughout inside the for loop.

```
date = re.match(r'\d{2} \w+ \d{2}', line).group(0)
time = line.split()[3]
...
```

Comment: The next error I ran into is "AttributeError: 'Nonetype' object has no attribute 'group'